# How do I query multiple sheets referencing a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get the average value across multiple tabs in a google sheet, using different sets of criteria.

One of this is if the Date in column 1 is equal to the one in Cell B62 of tab "Sheet1"

The query works on the first two criteria but not on the date one.

> =QUERY({'Raw Data - Google Ads'!A:L,'Raw Data - Bing Ads'!A:Q},"select Avg(Col11) where Col4 contains 'EMEA' and Col4 contains 'BKWS' and
>   Col1 contains '&Sheet1!B62&'",1)

No error message is displayed, the query result is just blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google query needs the following specific syntax for comparing dates:

```
where startDate < date "2008-03-18"
```

[Ref docs here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals).

The fix may be:

```
=QUERY({'Raw Data - Google Ads'!A:L,'Raw Data - Bing Ads'!A:Q},"select Avg(Col11) where Col4 contains 'EMEA' and Col4 contains 'BKWS' and Col1 contains date '"&TEXT(Sheet1!B62,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Essentially, use `date` with the date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.